# C# refactoring of boilerplate

Tags: c#, inheritance, refactoring

I'm currently working on a project, where I have a blueprint for how my Worker class is defined, the Worker class is located in a SharedLibraryModel in a different solution folder.

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService
        {
        private readonly Controller _controller;
        private string ListenQueueName;

        public Worker(Controller controller, string listenQueueName)
        {
            _controller = controller;
            ListenQueueName = listenQueueName;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
          
        }
```

I have also made a Controller class and IController interface.

```
 public class Controller : IController
    {
        public (string, string) MessageReceived(string inMessage)
       {
        return ('some', 'string')
       };
  
    }
```

I want to use the above definition of a Worker class in my CustomerWorker, which I have defined as

```
public class CustomerWorker : SharedModelLibrary.Worker
    {
        public CustomerController _customerController;
        public readonly string ListenQueueName = 'customers';

        public CustomerWorker(CustomerController _customerController, string ListenQueueName)
            : base(_customerController, ListenQueueName)
        {

        }
```

The CustomerController inherits from the Controller.

But when the following is called in Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomerMessage, CustomerService>(); 
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CustomerController>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<CustomerWorker>();

var app = builder.Build();
```

I get the error message

```
"Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service
descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton
 ImplementationType: CustomerMicroService.CustomerWorker': Unable to resolve service for type 
'System.String' while attempting to activate 'CustomerMicroService.CustomerWorker'.)"
```

I'm not sure if its improper use of inheritance or something I have misunderstood in regard to the AddHostedService and AddSingleton.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The constructor name in your CustomerWorker class looks incorrect. It should be the same name as the class, no? And which class do you want to inject? The Worker class or the CustomerWorker class (or either/both?)

Comment: Yes, I have corrected the type in the post. I want to inject the CustomerWorker

Comment: You are trying to inject a CustomerWorker? but this is not what your class constructors do. It is the Controller that is being injected.

Comment: What would I need to change for the controller to be injected correctly?

Comment: A common pattern is to use parameter injection in your constructors - the controller would take a CustomerWorker as a parameter in the Controller constructor. The DI system would take care of new-ing it up when the constructor is called. You did this for CustomWorker (it takes a controller in its constructor). Did you mean to do the opposite?

Comment: I would like to parse my CustomerController through my CustomerWorker, so I can use all of the functionality that is in the Worker class. I thought that was what I'm doing

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by parsing (passing?) a controller through a background service. To speak generally, if you inject a class into another class, it makes that functionality of that class available in the class it is injected into. No doubt that is what you want - but I'm confused as to which class you mean to inject into which other class ... what you are saying and what your code is doing don't seem to match up (besides the fact that you have runtime errors - but first, clarify what you want to inject where...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is very clear. `Unable to resolve service for type  'System.String'`, It seems you want to inject `string ListenQueueName` into `CustomerWorker` class. but you have not register string type. I know it is impossible to register string type.
I don't know the `ListenQueueName` purpose.
you have two way to solve your issue.

1. register `Customerworker` by handle like below:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<CustomerWorker>(sp => 
{
   var customerController = sp.GetRequiredService<CustomerController>();

  return new CustomerWorker(customerController, "ListenQueueName");

});
```

2. wrapper your `ListenQueueName` into a class and then register that class.